# .htaccess redirect traffic hitting .html links to TLD homepage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm helping a client migrate an old site which used .html extension at the end of the web address to a properly named URL structure.  I want to do a redirect for all URLs that end in .html to the homepage.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1http://domain.org [NC]
```

Comment: is the file on the same domain (domain.org)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should fit you needs:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ / [QSA,R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use sometihing like this:

```
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ([^/]+)\.html$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

or for permanent redirect

```
  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ / [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: I would add also a case for home page

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but just based on your code I think this will work for you:

```
RewriteRule \.html$ http://domain.org/? [R,L,NC]
```

This will redirect every URL ending with `.html` to `http://domain.org/` even stripping out any query parameter in the original URI.